# Applying custom CSS to a page based on custom ID or class

Tags: templating, css

I want to apply custom CSS to 1 page and am wondering if there is an easy way to do either of the following:

-add some code to the Craft Template file that has the opening  tag that can add an ID based on page slug

-or add a custom body id to any specific page within the "Entries" panel on the backend.

thanks in advance for any insight!
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your template architecture is set up, it could be as simple as using the [`css` tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/tags.html#css)...

```
{% css %}
/* Any CSS that applies only to this page */
.example {
    color: red;
}
{% endcss %}
```

Comment: You might want to add to your example with a field in the backend and `{% css %}{{ entry.cssFieldMarkup }}{% endcss %}`  or `{% if entry.id == ID %}{% css %}...{% endcss %}{% endif %}`. @Andy: in general I always prefer to have the info in the entry as a field (your second approach).

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to add the entry id as a style hook and then scope your styles to that:

`<body class="{% if entry %} entryId-{{ entry.id }}{% endif %}">`

Then in your css simply target the ID, e.g:
`.entryId-19 { color: #bada55 }`